# Is it frowned upon to alternate between churches of different denominations?

Tags: christian-living, denomination

Is it frowned upon to alternate between churches? Especially churches of different denominations? The intention is to explore the differences and find a better fit.

Comment: While not necessarily a bad question, it needs to be worded better to be suitable for this site; the main thing missing is, according to whom are you worried it might be a bad thing? As a non-denominational churchgoer I would highly encourage trying different churches, but also researching individual denominations online as even a few visits won't give you the whole picture of their theology.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify "by whom". Church leaders may frown upon things that God does not frown upon.

Comment: Most 'places of worship' are public and are available to voluntary attendance by anyone, unless they are disruptive. Some are private and require invitation as long as the attendee is 'favourably disposed' to the gathering and its purposes. I suggest that only a single attendance (maybe two or three) will be sufficient to decide whether, or not, one is of the same spirit and disposition as the gathering. If one continues to wander, it may well say something about the current condition of what is generally and broadly called 'the church'.

Comment: Most local Churches (in the US, at least) have websites in which they delineate their core beliefs.  That is a great place to start searching.

Comment: It is not very unusual for children, and even parents, of mixed families to alternate between Church of England and Roman Catholic services. Both the Protestant and Catholic clergy tend to disapprove of this, but it is accepted.

Comment: Do you literally mean "alternate", as in visit one church one week and a second the next, then back to the first etc. Or do you mean skip from one church to any other church as the fancy takes you? If you mean the first, what is the reason? Are you in different places alternate weekends?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, I meant both possibilities. Same place

Answer (score 3):

**Is it frowned upon to alternate between churches of different denominations?**

For some denominations **yes**, but for others **no**.

> The New Testament does not directly address the subject of attending two or more different churches. Paul’s letter to the Corinthians begins, “To the church of God in Corinth” (1 Corinthians 1:2), indicating one church, whereas the book of Galatians begins with “to the churches in Galatia” (Galatians 1:2), indicating more than one in the area. In any case, either people did not attend more than one gathering, or the issue did not warrant Paul’s attention. Today, however, with multiple local churches in cities—and even in small towns—the question of whether to attend more than one church on a regular basis does arise.
>
> The question becomes whether we can effectively pray, fellowship, sit under teaching, and use our spiritual gifts with two or more groups of Christians at the same time. Because the Bible is silent on the issue, we cannot be dogmatic about it. But what we can do is address the issue of motivation—what prompts Christians to feel led to spread their church attendance around to multiple churches and what are the effects and implications of doing so.
>
> Sadly, too often people “church hop” to more than one local body with the intention of picking and choosing something from each one because they feel they cannot find one church that “meets their needs” or gives them everything they think they should be getting from a church. They may attend one church for the music, another for the preaching, and a third for the social gatherings. The problem with this line of thinking is that Christians are to align themselves with a group of believers in order to give, not to get. We are to be actively serving and ministering to one another with the spiritual gift we have received from the Spirit, and when we spend minimal time in each group, we cannot do that effectively. In addition, we give the impression that we are not committed to the believers or the leadership in any one church, and that is a poor witness to others.
>
> While there may be legitimate reasons for someone to attend two or more churches, and nothing in the Bible forbids it, it is hard to see how such a practice could fully benefit either the believer or the local churches he or she attends. - [Is it wrong to attend two (or more) different churches?](https://www.gotquestions.org/two-churches.html)

Some denominations nevertheless really frown on this like the [Catholic](https://relevantradio.com/2017/10/as-a-catholic-can-i-go-to-a-protestant-service/) and Orthodox Churches. These Churches hold that they are the true Churches and as such visitations to others churches should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Denominations** The phenomenon of the Christian religion having many denominations can be quite befuddling! A newspaper cartoon once had a character saying, "It's a whole smorgasbord out there!" Fortunately, most of the Protestant churches subscribe to the same Fundamentals of Christianity (Apostles Creed, Nicene Creed, etc.) But along with these basic beliefs, each denomination adds an idiosyncrasy, a quirk, a custom, a tradition that makes them distinct. Most of these are minor, dealing with style of worship, type of baptism, appeal to a certain age group, and the like.

Some denominations were started over disputations about a particular doctrine, while still subscribing to the other major received doctrines of Christianity.  There are books that list all these denominations, giving their history as well as their major doctrinal emphases. (Handbook of Denominations). It would be well to consult one of these books and see which appeals most to your understanding of Christianity...of Jesus.

**Church Home** Eventually, however, it is strongly beneficial to settle down and call one of the local churches, *home*. Christianity is not just a theological club for studying doctrine, nor a holiday observation gathering place. It is a vital community of believers, so much intertwined, and interconnected that the Bible called it a **Body**.

> For as the body is one and hath many members, and all members of that one body, being many, are one body, so also is Christ (Christianity). For by one Spirit we are baptized into one Body, whether we be Jew or Gentile, whether we be bond or free; and have been all made to drink into one Spirit.

> For the body is not one member, but many...But now God hath set the members every one of them in the Body, as it has pleased Him...(See whole chapter 1 Corinthians 12)

The local church Body is a community where believers can encourage one another...exhort one another...teach one another...strengthen one another...correct one another...restore one another...comfort one another...supply one another...etc. Each member supplies (ministers to) the other just like a human, physical body has members that work together to make the whole person function productively. The church is a place of fellowship and worship. It is where people learn to "love God and love people."

**Lone Ranger, Lone Stranger** The habit of moving around from church to church, visiting a different church, or church hopping, defeats the main purpose of the local church's existence. *God setteth the solitary in families* is an ancient saying that expresses the will of God for each believer too. (Psalm 68:6) The Church Family means a lot to the Father. It is where people become *brothers and sisters*. (See 1 Peter 2:17, Hebrews 13:1) Settling into one Body will be rewarding in the long run. Doing so is not just a good thing, it's a God thing!